# Trying to change element behaviour by changing its class. - .on("Click")

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, button, jquery-selectors

I'm building a web application and am learning as I go.
This is the first question that I am posting.

I have created a series of SPAN elements ,that behave like buttons.
After I click an element (the Orange one), I want to effectively disable it by changing its class (and hence its colour to Grey).

Firebug before .on("click):

```
<span class="sample_but3 sample_butOrange">3</span>
```

Firebug after .on("click"):

```
<span class="sample_but3 sample_butGrey">3</span>
```

I can see, using firebug, that the class ".sample_butOrange" is removed and the class ".sample_butGrey" is added exactly as I expect.
But its the next bit that has got me stumped.

Now if I click the Grey button (which was originally Orange) I'm still get alerted that I pressed the Orange button, instead of being alerted that I pressed the Grey one.

NOTE: I have put in alerts that notify which button is pressed.

Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Here is the full code as an example:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample_button.css">
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script>

        // Grey button means do nothing.
        function sample_processGrey() {
            alert("You pressed the grey button. Don't do anything as this button is disabled.");
        }

        function sample_processOrange() {
            alert("You pressed the orange button");
            $(".sample_but3").addClass("sample_butGrey").removeClass("sample_butOrange");
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Do something when the buttons are pressed.
            $(".sample_butGrey").on("click", sample_processGrey);
            $(".sample_butOrange").on("click", sample_processOrange);
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <span class="sample_but1 sample_butPurple">1</span>
    <span class="sample_but2 sample_butGreen">2</span>
    <span class="sample_but3 sample_butOrange">3</span>
    <span class="sample_but4 sample_butRed">4</span>
    <span class="sample_but5 sample_butBlue">5</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Clue: event delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't attach events to elements that don't exist yet. But you can attach events to parent elements that do exist, and then look for the child target. jQuery makes this easy with event delegation. Here is an example:

`$("body").on("click", ".sample_butGrey", sample_processGrey);`

This tells jQuery to attach an event to the body tag, and to look for an element with the class sample_butGrey when clicked. If found call the sample_processGrey method. Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/AyQq8/4/

Comment: I tested your change and it works well. Your jsfiddle example is a copy of my code. (ie dowsnt have your suggested change in it).

Answer (score 0):

The onClick event is place on the JQuery element selected when the DOM is ready.
If you need to change the click event, you could add it to the target button in the same time to change the button class.

I hope it may help you to understand this issue.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
function sample_processGrey() {
    alert("You pressed the grey button. Don't do anything as this button is disabled.");
}

function sample_processOrange() {
    alert("You pressed the orange button");
    $(".sample_but3").addClass("sample_butGrey").removeClass("sample_butOrange");
}


// Do something when the buttons are pressed.
$(".sample_butGrey").on("click", sample_processGrey);
$(".sample_butOrange").on("click", sample_processOrange);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3G52h/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `.hasClass()` to determine the current class? Or have you tried fetching the class to determine what it is before choosing a dynamic response with `elm.attr('class')` ? You can also use `.find()` to find the new class added in the content of the container and re-select it again like: `$('body').find('.sample_butGrey').on('click', function(){ /* New gray was clicked */ })` If it doesn't exist, clearly it's not there, so you can run a fail response or something else.